# Coredata performBlock then return the new value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsthread

How to return the new object saved in coredata if I am using `performBlock` to save a managedObjectContext?

The requirement is, add an entry in coredata, and return it. My code is something like this:

```
//create a privateMOC
NSManagedObjectContext *private = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

//set parentContext
[private setParentContext:self.coredataManager.managedObjectContext];

__block Detail *object = nil;

[private performBlock:^{
    //fetch from the db
    object = [self.coredataManager insertObjectWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([Detail class])];

    //save the private context
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![private save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
    }

}];

return object;
```

Here since the saving is happening in Block, the return will execute first. But I need the `object` with the latest value. Any suggestion please.

Comment: You do not want to use `performBlockAndWait`.  It causes the calling thread to block, and can cause deadlock issues if not done carefully.  In general, you should avoid `performBlockAndWait` unless there is no other solution.  I have found this to be extremely rare.

Furthermore, you can't do anything with the object you are returning outside of another `performBlock` anyway, except maybe stash it somewhere for later reference.

So, why return it at all?  Why not do whatever you were going to do with it inside the `performBlock`?

Comment: The newly created value is passed to several places including background applications/process.

Comment: @JodyHagins : Plz see my comment

Comment: And why can't it be "passed to several places" from inside the `performBlock` code?

Comment: @JodyHagins: This block is of return type void. Please check.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that you don't need to return anything.  There is no reason to wait for it to complete and return something.  You should be able to do what you want inside that block.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than **return** the newly created Core Data object, pass the constructor method a block with a parameter of the type of object you're creating.

When the object has been created within the Managed Object Context's `performBlock:` block, call your `completion` block and pass in the newly constructed Core Data object.

```
+ (void)coreDataObjectWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)json completion:(void (^)(NSYourCoreDataObject *coreDataObject))completion {

    [yourManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:... inManagedObjectContext:...];

        NSYourCoreDataObject *coreDataObject = [[NSYourCoreDataObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:...];

        if (completion) {
            // "return" the new managed object
            completion(coreDataObject);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that was not too difficult to fix this issue:

I replaced `performBlock` with `performBlockAndWait` and it worked.

**Reason** is straightforward: `performBlock` is asynchronous, while `performBlockAndWait` is synchronous.

Comment: Just remember that it's blocking and that you're returning it linked to a temporary context so you need to take care to only access it in that context (which no-one actually looks to own...)

Comment: performAndWait is not just a synchronous version of perform. it has order of operations differences as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214574/354876