# Xcode Multithreading violation"All that is left to us is honor cocoa"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, core-data

I've use coredata in my project and sometimes, not always, it crashes and I get the error as shown in the screen shot.

I am using coredata which resembles from here https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Could someone help me to understand this and guide me to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: You linked to a very general discussion of how you set up a separate Managed Object Context that you can use to do operations in the background. You don't say anything about what you are doing, so we can't help you. And your screen-shot only shows the stack trace, not the error message you are getting. You need to provide a LOT more information if you want help.

Comment: @DuncanC: I have used coredata at least 100K lines directly & indirectly in the application, I can't figure it out which code is showing the above.

Comment: You have to be careful to use the regular MOC for normal core data calls, and a separate one that you set up with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType using the performBlock method, and not mix them up. My guess is that you are using the wrong MOC somewhere.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - I imagine this is related to your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563578/coredata-performblock-then-return-the-new-value).  Maybe you are misusing that object you get from `performBlockAndWait` because you wanted to have it after the block was performed.  You cant' do **anything** with a core data object outside the protection of `performBlock`.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - Look at the code in `-[XXCoreDataManager objectWithEntityName:withAttributeKey:andValue:sortDescriptorKey:context:]`.  If there is no `performBlock` in there, then there must be one wrapping the call of that method.

Answer (score 3):

The "multithreading violation" part is a big clue. Also the fact that you seem to be doing something GCD-related in a different thread.

Core Data is not thread safe. You can't fetch a managed object on one thread and use it on another. Since you didn't post any code, it's impossible to say exactly what went wrong in this specific case. You should turn on `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` as described in [this blog post](https://medium.com/bpxl-craft/some-lessons-learned-on-core-data-5f095ecb1882), and it'll help you narrow down the cause of the crash.

A *common* mistake, which might or might not apply here, is not using `performBlock` and/or `performBlockAndWait` enough. You need to do that for all Core Data-related operations, even things as simple as reading the value of a managed object attribute.

Comment: Thats true, I'm forced to use `performBlockAndWait` since I needed to return some value after fetching it....

Comment: @Tom - I'm pretty sure he already has `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` enabled since that's how he got the 'All that is left to us is honor' stack frame, which, BTW, is one of the most clever names ever.